# How to cut the object?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image: follows this one][[image: How to cut like this1]

How to cut something like this I've been thinking about for a long time and I have no idea. Anyone, please help me to make it possible.

Comment: You may want to use the `knife` tool in blender.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a cylinder, rip its front edge, mirror:

[image]

Deform it with the *Proportional Editing* option:

[image]

Close the inner topology, etc:

[image]